# Crazy modules behaviour in Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-module, angular-lazyloading

I created some components that use other components. All components works fine except the last I created. This is the code in HTML:

```
<window [(ngModele)]="isOpen"></window>
```

This is the module of my new component:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ComponentsModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        MyNewComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        MyNewComponent
    ]
})
export class MyNewModule { }
```

In imports there is `ComponentsModule` that contains `WindowComponent`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        PipeModule,
        RouterModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        WindowComponent,
        // OTHER COMPONENTS
    ],
    exports: [
        WindowComponent,
        // OTHER COMPONENTS
    ]
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

In this last component console show me this error on build:

```
src/app/areas/wins/my.new.component/my.new.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'window' is not a known element:
1. If 'window' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

Add `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` and `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` is completely useless. What's wrong with Angular modules?

Comment: It is a weird naming decision - does changing the `window` selector to, say, `app-window` fix this?

Comment: @kvetis Actually the real name is `finestra`. I changed it to `window` only to translate all in english

Comment: Share the window component code as well

Comment: @YairCohen I solved right now. Problem was totally elsewhere. No words for Angular...

Comment: Please share the problem solver, thx, interested in this.

Comment: `[(ngModele)]` ?

Comment: @kvetis There was an HTML error in another component. This magicaly cause errors in some other places. I stopped asking questions and decided to move on. Angular has always had too many problems. Bad technology